# Swift: loading image asynchronously in UITableViewCell - Autolayout issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

In my `UITableViewCell` I have a `UIImageView` that download image asynchronously (with Kingfisher library). It's very similar to Instagram.

[image]

I'm using autolayout and I want to use `UITableView.automaticDimension` for row height. How should I set constraints so that the height of the cell becomes taller or shorter according to the image? If I set an initial constraint for the `UIImageView` height and change it once I download the image, I have at leat one element that changes its height to "fill" the space added (or removed) by the `UIImageView`.

Comment: You need to calculate the height of each cell manually according to the height of image.

Comment: That would be a real mess. However, where should I set the new height?

Comment: You must pass that in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` method.

Comment: The actual height is calculated inside the cell and after tableView(_:heightForRowAt:) is called. Refreshing the entire tableView every single time is the only option?

Comment: Yes. This is the only option to get the cell height according to the image after the image is downloaded. Else you must accept the image's aspectRatio in the API itself.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the aspect ratio preserved height using with actual size of the images and device screen sizes for each one, and update UIImageView height constraint on the UITableViewCell.

Just call feedCell.configure(with: FeedImage) on the tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)

```
// FeedImage data will be load from your API, in the best practices, you should get actual sizes of the image from your API

struct FeedImage {
    var url: String = ""
    var width: CGFloat = 0.0
    var height: CGFloat = 0.0
}

class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var feedImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var feedImageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func configure(with feedImage: FeedImage) {

        feedImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = getAspectRatioPreservedHeight(actualWidth: feedImage.width, actualHeight: feedImage.height)

        feedImageView.loadImage(with: feedImage.url) // Asynchronous image downloading and setting, you can use any library such as SDWebImage, AlamofireImage, Kingfisher or your custom asynchronous image downloader

    }

    // Calculate the aspect ratio preserved height using with actual size of the images and device screen sizes.
    private func getAspectRatioPreservedHeight(actualWidth: CGFloat, actualHeight: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        if (actualWidth == 0) { return CGFloat(400.0) }

        let newComputedHeight = (WIDTH*actualHeight)/actualWidth

        if newComputedHeight > (HEIGHT * 0.6) {
            return (HEIGHT * 0.6)
        }

        return newComputedHeight
    }

}
```

Comment: That's what I do, but the height of the cell is not correct because other items stretch to fit the original height of the cell that I define in the storyboard.

Comment: Set UITableViewAutomaticDimension for UITableView row height, and set approximate height of your cell for estimated row height

Comment: Not directly. My workaround was making my APIs sending me the image size before downloading it, so I could set UIImageView's height while setting the cell. It worked but just because I had the chance to edit APIs.

Comment: Yeah you are on the right way :) also you should download a cropped version of the image to fit on the uiimageview. The dimensions of the image to be downloaded must provide the same proportions as the calculated height.

Answer (score 0):

you have to Crop Image Propotionally and than save to KingFisher Cache.

```
let cached = ImageCache.default.imageCachedType(forKey: url)
        if cached != .none {
            getImageFromCache(key: url) { [weak self] (cachedImage) in
                self?.image = cachedImage
                self?.completionHandler?(cachedImage)
            }
        }
        else {
            getImageFromServer(key: url) { [weak self] (cahcedImage) in
                self?.image = cahcedImage
                ImageCache.default.store(cahcedImage, forKey: self!.url)
                self?.completionHandler?(cahcedImage)
            }
        }





 func getImageFromCache(key:String,complition:@escaping (UIImage)->()) {
        ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: url, options: nil) { [weak self] (image, cachetype) in

            guard let cachedImage = image , let opCancelled = self?.isCancelled , opCancelled == false  else {
                return
            }
            complition(cachedImage)
        }
    }

    func getImageFromServer(key:String,complition:@escaping (UIImage)->()) {
        if let imageUrl = URL(string: key) {
            KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: imageUrl, options: nil, progressBlock: nil) { [weak self] (image, error, cachetype, _ ) in
                if error == nil {
                    guard let cachedImage = image , let opCancelled = self?.isCancelled , opCancelled == false  else {
                        return
                    }


                        let finalheight = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(cachedImage.size.height)) / CGFloat(cachedImage.size.width)
                        let newImage = cachedImage.resize(targetSize: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: finalheight))
                        complition(newImage)

                }
                else {
                    print("Error ###### == Errror While Downloading Image")
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Error ###### == can't create Url of String")
        }
    }
```